# How can I sync pictures with all my computers via a server

Tags: backup, sync, windows-server-2012

I'm running a server in my basement and I would like to save all my pictures on it. So is there any software like "dropbox" that I could host?

I don't need my stuff in the cloud just on my server. But I would like to create a map on every computer on my network and when people drop pictures in that map all the pictures are synced to my server. So whatever computer I am, I've got always the same version of the map.

I found something like sparkleshare but are there any alternatives better ones?

Comment: Maybe create a standard share and make it available offline on all computers?

Comment: But then there is no syncing like dropbox does?

Comment: just make one share and map it on all pcs, then make a shortcut to that mapped drive wherever you want it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an alternative to sparkleshare, check OwnCloud:
http://owncloud.org/

If you just want to keep a (few) folders in sync on several computers, have a look at unison:
http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/

Answer (score 1):

Another app that could be of use to you is [Bittorent Sync](http://www.bittorrent.com/intl/fr/sync).
It wouldn't really run "on" the server as it's P2P (by this i mean you could install this only on your computers), but your server could run an instance of it if you want to store a backup of your pictures on it as well.

Amongst other positive points, it's quite fast, lightweight, and very easy to use.
Aaaaaand it runs on mobile OSes if you happen to be taking pictures with your smartphone.

Didn't know unison by the way, but it seems more power-user oriented.
If what you want is a specifically a Dropbox equivalent running on a server, i can only +1 the use of owncloud.

Answer (score -1):

Going to host owncloud on my server. Think this is the best solution. This is more stable then sparkleshare in my opinion. Also it has more features. The unison project is also possible but my feeling says to take the owncloud. Love the interface to.

Comment: Care to explain why you think its the best solution?

Comment: If you decided that another user's answer provided the best solution for you, you can click the check mark by their answer to accept the answer. This indicates to future visitors which answer worked best, and also indicates that the question has been solved.